# ios7 custom transition for navigationcontroller on tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios7, custom-transition

My ViewController hierachy is as follows:

```
UITabbarcontroller
->UINavigationController1
   ->FirstViewController
->UINavigationController2
   ->UIViewController
```

So I want to push a SecondViewController on top of my FirstViewController. The custom transition I need is for the SecondViewController to fade in and my FirstViewController to fade out.

Here is my code:

FirstViewController:

```
- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController* vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

UINavigationController1Delegate:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    MyAnimatedTransitioning *transitioning = [[MyAnimatedTransitioning alloc] init];
    return transitioning;
}
```

MyAnimatedTransitioning:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0;
    fromViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 0;
            toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        fromViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
        [transitionContext completeTransition:finished];
    }];
}
```

I use a push style instead of the present style so that the navigation bar can cross fade nicely. 
However the problem that I faced is that I still see my tabbar at the bottom(from the tabbarcontroller) being pushed to the left during the transition. What I need is for the tabbar to fade out nicely too. Anyone has any good ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using present style instead of the push style. Works well enough for me